# PHP Zend Framework 2 - Trouble rendering form - "form plugin not found"

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm having a problem rendering a form in view using ZF2. I'm following "Zend Framework 2.0 by Example" book by the word. Problem is, when rendering the form in the correspondent view, the following error pops out:

```
A plugin by the name "form" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\View\HelperPluginManager
```

I've ran across all types of errors, both here and in the ZF forums, but i couldn't find an answer to my question, so i'm all outta options.

Here is the relevant files:

```
// Module.php
namespace Users;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface {

    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return [
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => [
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ],
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
                'namespaces' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

}


//module.config.php
namespace Users;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'Users\Controller\Index' => 'Users\Controller\IndexController',
            'Users\Controller\Register' => 'Users\Controller\RegisterController',
        ]
    ],
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'users' => [
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/users',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => [
                    'register' => [
                        'type' => 'segment',
                        'options' => [
                            'route' => '/register[/:action]',
                            'constraints' => [
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ],
                            'defaults' => [
                                'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Register',
                                'action' => 'index',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'index' => [
                        'type' => 'segment',
                        'options' => [
                            'route' => '/index[/:action]',
                            'constraints' => [
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ],
                            'defaults' => [
                                'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Index',
                                'action' => 'index',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'convertercontent' => 'Zend\Form\Factory'
        ),
    ),
];

//RegisterForm.php
namespace Users\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Validator\EmailAddress;

class RegisterForm extends Form {
    public function __construct($name = null) {
        parent::__construct('register');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'name',
            'attributes' => [
                'type' => 'text',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Full Name',
            ]
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'email',
            'attributes' => [
                'type' => 'email',
                'required' => 'required',
                'id' => 'email',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Password',
            ],
            'filters' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'StringTrim',
                ],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                    'options' => [
                        'messages' => [
                            EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => 'Email address format is invalid',
                        ],
                    ],

                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'password',
            'attributes' => [
                'type' => 'password',
                'required' => 'required',
                'id' => 'password',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Password',
            ],
            'filters' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'StringTrim',
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'confirm_password',
            'attributes' => [
                'type' => 'password',
                'required' => 'required',
                'id' => 'confirm_password',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Confirm password',
            ],
            'filters' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'StringTrim',
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => [
                'type' => 'button',
                'id' => 'submit',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Submit',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}

//RegisterController.php
namespace Users\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Users\Form\RegisterForm;

class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction(){        
        $form = new RegisterForm();
        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
        return $viewModel;
    }

    public function confirmAction() {
        $viewModel = new ViewModel();
        return $viewModel;
    }
}

// register view index "index.phtml" (form page)
<section class="register">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <?php if ($this->error): ?>
        <p class="error">
            There were one or more issues with your submission.
            Please correct them as
            indicated below.
        </p>
    <?php endif
    ?>

        <?php        
        $form = $this->form;    
        $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url());    
        $form->prepare();    

    $form = $this->form;    
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL, array('controller' => 'Register', 'action' => '    process')));
    $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
    ?> 

    <dl class="zend_form">
        <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('name')); ?></dt>
        <dd><?php
            echo $this->formElement($form->get('name'));
            echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('name'));
            ?></dd>
        <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('email')); ?></
        dt>
        <dd><?php
            echo $this->formElement($form->get('email'));
            echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('email'));
            ?></dd>
        <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('password'));
            ?></dt>
        <dd><?php
            echo $this->formElement($form->get('password'));
            echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('password'));
            ?></dd>
        <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('confirm_
password')); ?></dt>
        <dd><?php
            echo $this->formElement($form->get('confirm_password'));
            echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('confirm_
password'));
            ?></dd>
        <dd><?php
            echo $this->formElement($form->get('submit'));
            echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('submit'));
            ?></dd>
    </dl>

    <?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

It seems the form plugin for the view isn't getting loaded, but I have no idea on how to load it or any other way to surpass this problem.

Answer (score 8):

Edit file **modules.config.php** which can be found under the **config/** directory and add following line:

```
'Zend\Form'
```

Like this:

```
return [
  'Zend\Form',
  'Zend\Db',
  'Zend\Router',
  'Zend\Validator',
  'Application',
];
```

Comment: Same issue experienced with ZF3 when forgetting to setup config correctly during instalation of skeleton application.
Basically the libraries where available via composer/autoload but the plugins not activated hence the view helpers not activated. Thank you, this helped resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit **modules.config.php**

Actual path(in my project) /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/config/modules.config.php

add
Zend\Form',
 in return array(
)

My File looks like this

return array(

```
'Zend\Form',
'Zend\Router',
'Zend\Validator',
'Application',
'BookList'
```

);

Answer (score -1):

Viewhelper needs update the below:

```
$formHelper     = new Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form();
$labelHelper    = new Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormLabel();
$elementHelper  = new Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement();
$inputHelper    = new Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormInput();
$textareaHelper = new Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormTextarea();
$errorHelper    = new Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElementErrors();

echo $formHelper->openTag($form);
?>
<dl class="zend_form">
<dt><?php  
     $name = $form->get('name');
    echo $labelHelper->openTag($name) . $name->getLabel(); 
    echo $labelHelper->closeTag($name);
    ?>
</dt>
<dd><?php 
    echo $inputHelper($name);
    echo $errorHelper($name);
?></dd>
```

It will display what you want.